# Interface for Authentication

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am creating a login system which is using an interface and a public class I am just trying to think of the methods and properties I would need in the interface so far I have the following what are best practices and it also needs to be a custom interface not one prebuilt.

ValidateUser is cheking against username and password and update database is used when the user is sucesfully loged in to update the tables

```
interface IAuthentication
{
    Boolean ValidateUser(string username, string password);
    Boolean UpdateDatabase(string username, string password);
}
```

Comment: what is your question? just need few ideas about possible methods?

Comment: Why don't you use the same methods the built-in IAuthentication method uses? See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff422650(v=vs.91).aspx

Comment: You might want to look at SecureString for passing password around: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Or the various Membership classes in System.Web.Security http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Web.Security(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Or you could do it the WCF way if you re using WCF http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702565(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I think you are in danger of reinventing the wheel. There are several authentication frameworks around that cater for different scenarios (web app, web services, windows apps) and provide really good abstractions, standard implementations etc. You will almost certainly be wasting effort to do it all yourself, and most likely you will not do as good a job as the specialist frameworks (no offence intended).

Comment: @MikeGoodwin it depends on requirements for portability and access control. It may be perfectly pertinent to hide away the inner workings of an authentication mechanism to, say, a UI that only must know about passing login / password info and knowing if it succeeded or not.

Comment: Its part of a test to be honest was just asking advice on what methods a class should have thanks